# Is there a GLPK parameter that affects convergence?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cvxpy, glpk, mixed-integer-programming

I'm using [GLPK_MI](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) to solve a Mixed Integer Linear Program via [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/).
Whenever my problem grows beyond about 2000 constraints, the solver does not converge and just keeps on running.
When I removed some redundant constraints to stay below 2000 constraints, the same problem is solved in seconds.

Is there some internal parameter that I can set (via cvxpy?) that somehow creates this 2000 constraints limit?

**Context**: The redundant constraints were a result of how the equations
were generated and I assumed would just be pruned or inferred by the solver anyway.
For example, things like:

1. `0<=X_i`
2. `X_i<=N`
3. `sum(X_i)<=N`

for all *binary* X_i.
Since `X_i` is *binary* (i.e. non-neg) I can drop (1) and since I have (3) I can drop (2) as well.

Comment: No. Look for some basic introduction into integer-programming to understand how important *heuristics* are and what those mean in regards to *expected behaviour*. It's hard to foresee things in these solvers (except for *some* things like integrality gaps). Variance is usually very high and therefore people use timeouts or mip-gaps to accept sub-optimal solutions (if finding integral solutions is not the problem).

Comment: I'm aware of this, and yet, when I tried different versions on my problem with different data, this 2000 constraints threshold seemed to hold - hence my thought that it is some kind of parameter.

Comment: No there is not. We don't know what you are doing exactly (and specifics matter in the NP-hard world), but maybe you observe something like the well-known phase-transition effect in SAT (~ hardness of instances suddenly changes).

Comment: I was afraid you'd say something like that... Is there a way to tell the solver to stop earlier with some time limit or incremental improvement threshold?

Comment: As i said: time-limit and mip-gaps are supported in every MIP-solver. Look at cvxpy's documentation how to pass options (and probably into glpks / cvxopt's documentation to find the relevant options). This stuff is a bit more work due to cvxpy using cvxopt (python with c-code wrapper) which calls glpk (c code). Therefore you might need to consult all 3 manuals to reason about correct param-setting.

Comment: I only saw cvxopt options in the [docs](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html?highlight=solver#setting-solver-options). Do you know if any of them are relevant for time-limit or mip-gaps?

Comment: None of those. As i said: you need to consult all 3 manuals and look if and how options are passed through. It's annoying, i know. Maybe a global usage of [this](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/blob/8713390fa2a18110c6174dd8b5ceecefe64935e5/tests/test_glpk.py#L52) + `mipgap=0.1` would work (although very hacky). But that's only guessing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. 

Comment: For larger problems, I typically try out different solvers. In some cases, this can make a big difference.